# How to highlight a cell with 2 parameters in Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to highlight individual cells in a column if:
1)that cell is todays date or in the past
2)if the cell next to it is blank

Both of these conditions must be true but I'm having a hard time using IF/AND statements

[image: Sample Data]

In this image I would need only D2 to be highlighted

I've tried and failed with all these formulas in conditional formatting

```
=AND(TODAY()-1,INDIRECT("RC[1]",ISBLANK)

=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("RC[1]"))AND(TODAY()-1))

=IF((ISBLANK($E10))*($D10<TODAY()))

=IF(($D10<TODAY()),"",IF(ISBLANK($E10),""

=AND(ISBLANK($E10),$D10<TODAY())
```

Comment: try `=AND(D2<=TODAY(),ISBLANK(E2))`. Note `ISBLANK` will not work if the cell contains a formula. If that is the case try `E2=""` instead

Comment: D2 would in fact not get highlighted in your way of thinking. Did you mean D3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting doesn't use 'If' statements  because it's understood, so you were closer with your =AND statements.

Try:

```
=AND($A2<=TODAY(),ISBLANK($B2))
```

Place this formula in the conditional formatting and adjust the cell references for A2 and B2 as needed. Then set the formatting and apply it to the rest of the column.

Comment: This works but does not un-highlight the cell if either conditions are changed. I need the cells to change (highlight) in real-time as data is entered.

Comment: It should be updating in real-time as changes are made. It would appear this is an option set for the sheet through visual basic.
  - On the sheet, press Alt+F11 which should pull up the editor.
  - In the View menu, select "Properties Window"
  - Locate the "EnableFormatConditionsCalculation" option and set it to True.
You'll need to do this for all tabs where you want the Conditional Formatting to automatically update.
Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/conditional-formatting-does-not-update/08fed959-df7a-4e43-a0ae-a2aa5f587edd

Comment: @Cont456 Let me know if the above comment helped you any further, as I'm curious if you were able to get this working or not.